# Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a search page. I need to only return a list of themedetails for themes that contain all of the themetag id's that are stored in the int[] ST. Currently the line (ST == null ? true : ST.Contains(b.ThemeTagID)) seems to give me an error

Additional information: Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

```
    public ActionResult Index(int ProviderID = 0, string Description = null, int[] ST = null)
    {

        var themedetail = from t in db.ThemeDetail
                          from b in t.ThemeTags
                          where (
                          (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description) ? true : t.Description.ToLower().Contains(Description.ToLower())) &&
                          (ProviderID == 0 ? true : t.ProviderID == ProviderID) &&
                          (ST == null ? true : ST.Contains(b.ThemeTagID))
                              )
                          select t;

        ViewBag.ProviderID = new SelectList(db.ProviderDetails, "ProviderID", "ProviderName");
        ViewBag.MultiselectFeatures = new MultiSelectList(db.ThemeFeatures, "ThemeFeatureID", "ThemeFeaturesName");
        ViewBag.MultiselectTags = new MultiSelectList(db.ThemeTags, "ThemeTagID", "TagName");

        return View(themedetail.ToList());
    }
```

The Models are...

```
[Table("ThemeDetail")]
public class ThemeDetail : Entity
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string ThemeName { get; set; }
    public ThemeDetail()
    {
        ThemeFeatures = new List<ThemeFeature>();
        ThemeTags = new List<ThemeTag>();
        ThemeImages = new List<ThemeImage>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ThemeFeature> ThemeFeatures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ThemeTag> ThemeTags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ThemeImage> ThemeImages { get; set; }
}

[Table("ThemeTags")]
public class ThemeTag
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Theme Tag ID")]
    public int ThemeTagID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tag Name")]
    [Required]
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ThemeDetail> ThemeDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `ST` inside your query but it can't be translated to SQL because ST is `int[]` and can be `null`) and in SQL there isn't any notion of *array*.

If you change your query to avoid `null` checking EF will be able to translate that query using `WHERE ThemeTagID IN (...)` with values provided from your list (be careful if list may come from another query with thousands of elements):

```
public ActionResult Index(int ProviderID = 0...
{
    if (ST == null)
        ST = new int[0];
```

Then simply change this:

```
(ST == null ? true : ST.Contains(b.ThemeTagID))
```

To this:

```
ST.Contains(b.ThemeTagID)
```