# Can a C# method allow nullable lists as parameters?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a method that allows for a list of Ids to search for, but I would like to allow the list to be optional. I've seen examples of `List<string>` but I'm having trouble with `List<Guid>`.

Trying this method in LinqPad, I get the message:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

Here's the method:

```
public static ICollection<Project> GetProjectsAllowed
(
    this IMkpContext db,
    Guid profileId,
    List<Guid> profOrgIds = null
)
{
    var projects = (from p in db.Project.Include(p => p.Proposals)
                    join po in db.ProfileOrganization on p.CreatedById equals po.ProfileId
                    where (profOrgIds == null || profOrgIds.Contains(po.OrganizationId))
                        && p.IsActive && po.IsActive
                    select p);

    return projects.ToList();
}
```

***UPDATE:*** Thanks to your comments, here's what I did:

```
public static ICollection<Project> GetProjectsAllowed
(
    this IMkpContext db,
    Guid profileId,
    List<Guid> profOrgIds = null,
    List<Guid> projectIds = null
)
{
    var projects = (from p in db.Project.Include(p => p.Proposals)
                    where p.IsActive
                    select p);

    if (profOrgIds != null && profOrgIds.Any())
    {
        var profileIds = db.ProfileOrganization
            .Where(po => po.IsActive && profOrgIds.Contains(po.OrganizationId))
            .Select(po => po.ProfileId);
        projects = projects.Where(p => profileIds.Contains(p.CreatedById));
    }

    if (projectIds != null && projectIds.Any())
        projects = projects.Where(proj => projectIds.Contains(proj.ProjectId));

    return projects.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why not create an overload that doesn't take a `List<Guid>`. Have a `private` method which returns an unfiltered collection of projects and if you are in the overload with the `List<Guid>` actually filter based on the collection? The other overload can simply return the unfiltered collection.

Comment: It sounds like this isn't a *C#* error, but an *Entity Framework* error...

Comment: @StephenRoss, that would fetch all projects from database. The problem is with EF (it can't do something, but what exactly I don't know). See [other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23387016/1997232) with same error.

Comment: @Sinatr I'm meaning to choose to check if the `profOrgIds` contains the `OrganizationId` or not. With the code as is it will select all active projects when the List is `null`, simply move the filtering to another method which has a single responsibility to filtering the collection instead of trying to handle both cases in the same method.

Answer (score 5):

A C# method can accept null lists. The problem you have is with the LINQ query itself.

You cannot pass a NULL check on the `profOrgIds` list into an Entity Framework related LINQ query, since the Entity Framework LINQ provider (which is in use here, as you are executing LINQ queries against an EF database context object) has no way to translate the query syntax into equivalent T-SQL.

In other words, get rid of

`profOrgIds == null`

from the query and you *should* be fine, but you will need to check profOrgIds  is null before you call the query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing to do with the optional `List<Guid>` parameter.  The offending line is in the LINQ query, and is a limitation of Entity Framework:

`where (profOrgIds == null...`

Essentially, Entity Framework doesn't know how to turn this into an equivalent SQL query.

A possible solution is to turn the condition into into a boolean, which EF should be able to handle (admittedly, this is untested):

```
var listIsNull = profOrgIds == null;
var projects = (from p in db.Project.Include(p => p.Proposals)
                join po in db.ProfileOrganization on p.CreatedById equals po.ProfileId
                where (listIsNull || profOrgIds.Contains(po.OrganizationId))
                    && p.IsActive && po.IsActive
                select p);
```

Comment: One would think this would work, and it is elegant too. If EF complains about a null list even in this case, you could create a dummy list, as in: `var listIsNull = profOrgIds == null; if (listIsNull) { profOrgIds = new List<Guid>(); }` followed by the same query as in this answer.

Comment: Your solution is certainly the better one!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that null `List`s choke Entity Framework.

Put this before the query

```
profOrgIds = profOrgIds ?? new List<Guid>();
```

and remove the null-checking, code should be fixed.

Comment: Another way would be to use `profOrgIds?.Contains(po.OrganizationId) ?? true`, letting the query still be the only statement of the method.

Comment: This does of course assume you don't want to distinguish between a `null` List and an empty one

Comment: Shouldn't that be `profOrgIds = profOrgIds ?? new List<Guid> { new Guid(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, }), new Guid(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, }), /*...*/ };` where the `List<>` contains all possible guids? ;-)

Comment: @Rhumborl Yeah, the question looks like `null` should mean "any guid shall match" while an empty list should mean "no guid shall match".

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You are correct indeed, I missed the `||`... Gonna amend this, it's not accurate